# multimedia module cannot be found in Qt for android

Tags: android, qt, qtmultimedia

I use `MediaPlayer` qml type to play a music.I just put one single qml file for this project.And It runs perfect on windows.

When I build it an android. Debug says `module "QtMultimedia" plugin "declarative_multimedia" not found` for Release and `D/MediaPlayer(15621): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side` for Debug version.

I have add `QT += multimedia` in .pro file and it has network access privilege.

I use `Desktop Qt 5.2.0 MinGW 32bit` and `Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.0)`.

So is there anything I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer in Qt doc

> Multimedia Special Considerations
>
> Qt Multimedia, like the rest of Qt, supports Android versions 2.3.3 (API level 10) or later. There is however an exception for video output which requires Android versions 3.0 (API level 11) or later. This affects camera preview and video player features.
>
> Additionally, the Qt Multimedia Widgets module is not supported on Android, which means video display is only available using the VideoOutput and Video QML items.

And the default minimum required SDK set by Qt Creator is API
9.So I change it to 10 and the error don't show again.

And more, the `D/MediaPlayer(15621): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side` error didn't matter me to play the music at all.