# import QtMultimedia 5.8 fails with static libraries

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, debian, qml

I'm using static QT and CMake on Debian 9 and now I'm trying to add sound player functionality from QML.

I've added `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS ... Multimedia REQUIRED)` and also linked:

```
-lQt5Multimedia
-ldeclarative_multimedia
```

but when I'm using `import QtMultimedia 5.8` in my QML file I get:

```
module "QtMultimedia" plugin "declarative_multimedia" not found
```

I assume I have to use `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN` to import some plugin, but I can't find any plugin related to declarative multimedia.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multimedia module cannot be found in Qt for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732111/multimedia-module-cannot-be-found-in-qt-for-android)

Comment: What do you mean by "linked `-lQt5Multimedia`"? You need to link Qt libraries with `target_link_libraries(<target name> Qt5::Multimedia ...)`